# MySQL best way to query the database to display a check list

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I have 4 tables in a database that allow me to manage a kind of 'check list'. In a few words for each `pathology`, I have a big step (`process`) splited into a multiple of `tasks`. All of this is linked to a specific operation (`progress.case_id`) in a summary table.

```
database.pathology
+--------------+------------+
| id_pathology |    name    |
+--------------+------------+
|            1 | Pathology1 |
|            2 | Pathology2 |
|            3 | Pathology3 |
+--------------+------------+

database.process
+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| id_process |   name   | pathology_id | days_allocated |
+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 1          | BigTask1 | 2            | 5              |
| 2          | BigTask2 | 2            | 3              |
| 3          | BigTask3 | 2            | 6              |
| ...        | ...      | ...          | ...            |
+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+

database.task
+---------+-------+------------+
| id_task | name  | process_id |
+---------+-------+------------+
| 1       | Task1 | 1          |
| 2       | Task2 | 1          |
| 3       | Task3 | 1          |
| 4       | Task4 | 2          |
| ...     | ...   | ...        |
+---------+-------+------------+

database.progress
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+---------+
| id_progress | task_id | case_id | user_id |    date    | current |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+---------+
|           1 |       1 |     120 |       2 | 2015-11-02 |       1 |
|           2 |       2 |     120 |       2 | 2015-11-02 |       0 |
|           3 |       1 |     121 |       3 | 2015-11-02 |       1 |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+---------+
```

I have to display something like that

[image]

My question is : what is the most efficient way to proceed ?

Is is faster to query only one table (progress) to display the most and only then query the other to get the names of the differents process and days ?

Perhaps the joint function is more efficient ?

Or do you think my database structure is not the more appropriate ?

For each case we can have aproximaly 50 tasks, with a current field translated into a checkbox. A background script is also running. It analyzes the days provided based on the remaining days to determine if there could be a delay for this specific case.

For each case, the progress table is already filled with all the task related to the pathology of the case. And the current field is always '0' at the begining.

I already tried multiple things like

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT process_id,process.name FROM task, progress,process WHERE progress.task_id = task.id_task AND task.process_id = process.id_process AND progress.case_id = ?");     
$result->execute(array($id));
foreach($result as $row)
{
  echo "<b>".$row[1]."</b><br>";
  $result = $db->prepare("SELECT name,id_task FROM task WHERE process_id = ?");     
  $result->execute(array($row[0]));
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
      echo $row[0];
      $result = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id, date, current FROM progress WHERE progress.task_id = ? AND case_id = ?");     
      $result->execute(array($row[1], $id));
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
        if($row[2] == 0)
        {echo "<input type='checkbox' />";}
        else
        {
          echo "<input type='checkbox' checked/>";
          echo "user : ".$row[0]." date : ".$row[1]."<br>";
        }            
      }          
  }
```

But I am pretty sure that I am not doing it right. Should I change my database infrastructure ? Should I use a specific MySQL trick ? Or maybe just a more efficiant PHP processing ?

Comment: Nested queries where the inner queries used data from the outer queries can almost always be better written as a single `join`ed query.

Comment: To add to the comments from @MarcB  YOu should recognize nested queries as a software development anti-pattern.  You shouild ALWAYS look for an alternate way to solve the problem when you see this anti-pattern.  That is not to say there will always be a better approach, but as noted, you will almost always find this to be the case.

Comment: In MySQL, consider the `SET` datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of efficiency, a database query is one of the slowest operations that you can perform.  Anything that you can do to reduce the number of queries that you make will go a long way towards making your application faster.

But more important than that, your application needs to work as designed, which means that the developers need to understand what's going on, data shouldn't be hanging around just waiting to be overwritten, and the junior developer who will be tasked to maintain this in 3 years won't want to tear their hair out.

Fast is better than slow.

Slow is better than broken.

To your specific problem, if possible, never have a query inside of a loop.  Especially when that loop is controlled by data that you pull from that same database.  This is a code smell that calls for proper use of `JOIN`s.

A Google Image search for [SQL Join Diagrams](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+join+diagrams&tbm=isch) shows plenty of examples of Venn Diagrams that show the different types of data returned with each `JOIN`.  When in doubt, you usually want `LEFT JOIN`s.

So, let's identify your relationships:

- Pathology

  - Unused in your results.
  - Find a way to incorporate it into your query, since "Pathology2" appears in your mockup.
- Process

  - References Pathology in a one-to-many relationship. Each Process can have one Pathology, but each Pathology can have 0 or more Processes.
- Task

  - References Task in a one-to-many relationship. Task contains children of Process.
- Progress

  - References Task, as well as the not shown Case and User. Progress appears to be the details of a Task when referencing a specific Case and User.
  - I am assuming that there is a business constraint where task_id, case_id, and user_id must be unique... That is, user 1 can only have 1 Progress entry for task 1 and case 100.
  - Besides holding the details for a Task, also acts as a bridge between Task, Case, and User, giving many-to-many relationships to the three tables.  Since Task is a direct child of Process, and Process is a direct child of Pathology, it gives a many-to-many relationship to Pathology.
- Case

  - Inferred existence of this table.
  - Referenced by Task.
- User

  - Inferred existence of this table.
  - Referenced by Task.

Based on this table structure, our main groupings will be Case, Pathology, and User.

That is, if you're a logged in user and you want to look at your progress by Case, you would want to see the following:

```
Case 110:
    Pathology1:
        BigTask1:
            Task1: X
            Task2: []
        BigTask2:
            Task3: X
    Pathology2:
        BigTask3:
            Task4: []
Case 120:
    Pathology1:
        BigTask1: 
            Task1: []
```

We would want User ID == 1;
Our first sorting  would be based on Case
Our second sorting would be based on Pathology
Our third sorting would be based on Process
And our last sorting would be on Task...

Thus, the data to get our results above would be:

```
+------+------------+----------+-------+----------+
| case | pathology  | process  | task  | progress |
+------+------------+----------+-------+----------+
| 110  | Pathology1 | BigTask1 | Task1 | 1        |
| 110  | Pathology1 | BigTask1 | Task2 | 0        |
| 110  | Pathology1 | BigTask2 | Task3 | 1        |
| 110  | Pathology2 | BigTask3 | Task4 | 0        |
| 120  | Pathology1 | BigTask1 | Task1 | 0        |
+------+------------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Our 'ORDER BY' clause is from last to first... `ORDER BY task, process, pathology, case`...  We could sort it in PHP, but the database is better at it than we are. If your indexes are set up properly, the database might not even have to sort things, it'll just fetch it in order.

The query to get the above data for a specific user is:

```
SELECT
    prog.case_id AS case,
    path.name AS pathology,
    proc.name AS process,
    task.name AS task,
    prog.current AS progress
FROM
    pathology path
LEFT JOIN process proc ON path.id_pathology = proc.pathology_id
LEFT JOIN task ON task.process_id = proc.id_process
LEFT JOIN progress prog ON task.id_task = prog.task_id
WHERE prog.user_id = :userid
ORDER BY task, process, pathology, case
```

Your PHP might then be along the lines of

```
<?php

$sql = <<<EOSQL
SELECT
    prog.case_id AS case,
    path.name AS pathology,
    proc.name AS process,
    task.name AS task,
    prog.current AS progress
FROM
    pathology path
LEFT JOIN process proc ON path.id_pathology = proc.pathology_id
LEFT JOIN task ON task.process_id = proc.id_process
LEFT JOIN progress prog ON task.id_task = prog.task_id
WHERE prog.user_id = :userid
ORDER BY task, process, pathology, case
EOSQL;

$result = $db->prepare($sql);     
$result->execute(array(':userid' => $id));
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
    // array(5) {
    //     ["case"]=>
    //     int(110)
    //     ["pathology"]=>
    //     string(10) "Pathology1"
    //     ["process"]=>
    //     string(8) "BigTask1"
    //     ["task"]=>
    //     string(5) "Task1"
    //     ["progress"]=>
    //     int(1)
    // }
}
```

Comment: It would seem that your `ORDER BY` column order should be reversed from what you have shown if you wanted directly display results from the result set without having to place results into some sort of intermediary data structure that would allow grouping by case at the top level.

Comment: @MikeBrant Maybe, I haven't ran this directly, and it's been a while since I've had to write an `ORDER BY` clause. My understanding is that the DB will first sort by task, then by process, then by pathology, then by case, leaving everything in the same Case together.  If my assumption is wrong, it's easy enough to reverse the order of the columns.